# Re-metrizing a compact metrizable space to make a homeomorphism Lipschitz

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, lipschitz-functions

Let $(X, \rho)$ be a compact metric space, and $T : X \to X$ a homeomorphism of $X$ to itself. I know that this $T$ can fail to be Lipschitz, e.g. $X = [0, 1], Tx = \sqrt{x}$ with the standard metric $\rho(x, y) = |x - y|$ (I found this in another post on here, but I closed the tab before I could link that post here). What's less obvious to me, however, is whether I could give $[0, 1]$ another metric $\rho'$ compatible with the standard topology on $[0, 1]$ with respect to which $\sqrt{\cdot}$ is Lipschitz.

More generally, given a compact metrizable space $X$ and a homeomorphism $T : X \to X$ of $X$ to itself, is there a way to look at the *topological* properties of $T$ and discern whether $T$ could be made Lipschitz by endowing $X$ with an appropriate metric? I know there are several metrical properties which can be dependent upon which metric is being used, e.g. boundedness and Cauchy-ness, but I don't know to what extent Lipschitzness is visible in the topology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any continuous $T\colon X\to X$ (not necessarily a homeomorphism) and any metric $\rho$ on $X$ (with finite diameter, which is automatic if $X$ is compact), you can define a new metric $\rho'\colon X\times X\to[0,2\operatorname{diam}(X,\rho)]\subset\mathbb{R}$ by
$$
\rho'(x,x'):=\sum_{n\geq 0}2^{-n}\rho(T^nx,T^nx')
$$
Then $\operatorname{Lip}_{\rho'}(T)\leq 2$:
\begin{align*}
\rho'(Tx,Tx')&=\sum_{n\geq 0}2^{-n}\rho(T^{n+1}x,T^{n+1}x')\\
&=2\sum_{n\geq 1}2^{-n}\rho(T^nx,T^nx')\\
&\leq2\sum_{n\geq 0}2^{-n}\rho(T^nx,T^nx')=2\rho'(x,x')
\end{align*}

Comment: How do you know this new metric generates the desired topology?

Comment: Actually, I don't think this should be true, because non-expansive maps have topological entropy $0$, so if this $\rho'$ generated the same topology, then every $T$ would have topological entropy $0$.

Comment: It is standard result that $\sum_n 2^{-n}\operatorname{proj}_n^*d_n$ generates the product topology for countable products $\prod_n (X_n,d_n)$ if $(X_n,d_n)$ has uniformly bounded diameter.  And our metric is the result of pulling back the product metric via $x\in X\mapsto(x,Tx,T^2x,\dots)\in X^{\mathbb{N}}$ (which is homeo onto image).

Comment: How do we get the Lipschitz constant on $T$?

Comment: Oops, typo there should be 2 not 1.

Comment: You said this was a "standard result". Could you give me a reference?

Comment: See, e.g., Theorem 4.2.2 in [Engelking's *General Topology*](https://www.amazon.com/General-Topology-Sigma-Pure-Mathematics/dp/3885380064).